# Headers are not sending Ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

My Ionic app is not sending the Headers. Here is my Code.

```
async setAnzahlTische() {
let headers1 = new Headers();
headers1.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers1.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' ); 
headers1.set('Authorization', await this.storage.get('token'));
headers1.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers1.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
headers1.append('x-Trigger', 'CORS');

let tischid = 2;


let postData =  {

    'tischid' : tischid

  };
let tos = JSON.stringify(postData);

this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/updatedata', tos, {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        //this.router.navigate(['/home']);

    }, error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
}
```

So what am I missing? When I do headers1.get('Authorization') I get the Token I want. Everything works fine in Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like that it works finr

```
 this.http.post("YOUR URL", "PARAMETER", { headers: { Auth: token } });
```

Comment: When i try to import RequestOptions it says they are not available in /angular/common/https.

Comment: Add HttpHeaders() instead of headers

Comment: Than it gives me that error: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.

Comment: just do it like that 


 this.http.post("Your url", "Your params", { headers: { Auth: token } });

Answer (score 1):

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = header.append('Content-Type','application/json');
headers = header.append('Accept','application/json');
```